# Working with resources

Tags: asp.net, resx

there!
I'm working with asp.net 3.5 web-site. And I have such problem:
I have 3 aspx pages, that contain asp:Label control with name "LabelContent" and foreach page I have two resx files, that contain LabelContentResource.Text and LabelContent binds LabelContentResource to , for 2 cultures. Also I have content editing page. On this page admin choses page for edit and in WYSIWG editor I need to load appropriate resorce. Like so:

```
string pageForLoadName = "links.aspx.de-AT.resx";
string key ="LabelContent.Text";
string resValue= LoadREsource(pageForLoadName ,key );
```

How can I write LoadREsource fnction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of

```
public string LoadResource(string pageForLoadName,string key)
{
    return (String)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(pageForLoadName, key);
}
```

Also, don't think you need `pageForLoadName = "links.aspx.de-AT.resx";`

just `pageForLoadName = "links.aspx.de-AT";`

Comment: Is it possible to access the local resources (App_LocalResources) of a page from another?